# Failed to generate the sample for media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I recently started creating a ASP.net Web API

For some reason I keep receiving this error when viewing the auto generated help documentation:

[image]

This is for a POST method

Samples show up fine for application/json and application/xml

I'm not quite sure but the application/-x-www-form-urlencoded keeps showing up

I've googled the error quite a bit but can't quite find what might be causing this

I truly appreciate any help that can be provided, also please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is an expected behavior. HelpPage sample generation uses the actual formatters present on  the HttpConfiguration to 'write' the sample objects. FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter cannot 'write' any type, hence HelpPage cannot generate samples for it.
As a workaround you could explicitly supply a sample for a particular type (as shown in the Areas\HelpPage\App_Start\HelpPageConfig.cs's commented code).

```
config.SetSampleForType("[0]=foo&[1]=bar", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), typeof(IEnumerable<string>));
```

Comment: I was starting to suspect this was an expected behavior. Thanks for the info.

Comment: If you would ask me - it's totally unexpected behavior. If the help page can't produces those samples why show this type of requests? Is there any way to disable it?

Comment: Setting `debug="false"` in your web.config will prevent the error from showing and shows "Sample not available." instead.

Comment: Where in the webconfig should we put the `debug="false"` @DigitalDan? And yes I agree, it should never show this code to the outside user... it's ridiculous!

Comment: @MarkPieszak `<configuration>...<system.web>...<compilation debug="false" ...`  There may be other elements/attributes in between (where I've put ..., that shouldn't be changed).  See here for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z01xdh.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 8):

The answer helped me out but i got bored of writing an example for each type that the system didn't know about... what i ended up doing is this

```
Type[] types = { typeof(MyType), typeof(AnotherType), *add more here* };

foreach(Type t in types)
{
    List<string> propExample = new List<string>();
    foreach(var p in t.GetProperties())
    {
        propExample.Add(p.Name + "=value");
    }

    config.SetSampleForType(string.Join("&", propExample), new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), t);            
}
```

Someone could get clever and extend it so that it puts in default values based on type of property but this was enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm late to the party...

Borrowing from the answer from @Adween and attempting to satisfy the challenge.

> "Someone could get clever and extend it so that it puts in default values based on type of property..."

I made an attempt to insert sample values for the parameters.  I don't like that I have to URLEndcode the sample value, but I like the output better.

```
foreach ( Type t in new Type[] { typeof( MyType ) } )
{
    List<string> propExample = new List<string>();
    foreach ( var p in t.GetProperties() )
    {
        propExample.Add( p.Name + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode( config.GetHelpPageSampleGenerator().GetSampleObject(p.PropertyType).ToString() ) );
    }

    config.SetSampleForType( string.Join( "&", propExample ), new MediaTypeHeaderValue( "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ), t );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to Adween
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35607342/20446686
instead of adding type manually as in the script
Type[] types = { typeof(MyType), typeof(AnotherType), *add more here* };
we can dynamically add Types by

**Type[] types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();**

```
Areas\HelpPage\App_Start\HelpPageConfig.cs

uncomment
config.SetSampleForType("[0]=foo&[1]=bar", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), typeof(IEnumerable<string>));

Type[] types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();

foreach (Type t in types)
{
    List<string> propExample = new List<string>();
    foreach (var p in t.GetProperties())
    {
        propExample.Add(p.Name + "=value");
    }

    config.SetSampleForType(string.Join("&", propExample), new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), t);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).